# Using a command to renew the command

Tags: macros

I've got:

```
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\renewcommand{\test}{#1}}
```

in a class file to make setting the command cleaner in the document itself.

This all works if the document contains:

```
\test{some content}
```

and outputs 'some content' when `\test` is used in the document.

But when I try to set `\test` to a new value with

```
\test{some other content}
```

later, it seems to just output the value of `\test` and then 'some other content'.

How do I stop LaTeX expanding the `\test` and actually calling the `\renewcommand` to update the value?

Comment: You are using `\test` in two separate ways.  The first time it defines it for future use.  Thereafter, it uses the future-use definition for output.  It would make more sense to have two commands: `\newcommand{\settest}[1]{\renewcommand{\test}{#1}}` to define (and redefine) it and `\test` to use it.  In this case, you would need an initial `\def\test{}` definition, so that the `\renewcommand` would not choke.

Answer (score 4):

The first usage of `\test` will redefine `\test` to a command without argument, that just outputs the argument of the first call. So your suggestion will not work. You have to use something like:

```
\newcommand{\test}{}
\newcommand{\settest}[1]{\renewcommand{\test}{#1}}
```

Then you can use

```
\settest{some content}
\test, \test, \test% shows "some contents" three times
\settest{some other content}
\test, \test% shows "some other contents" two times
```

You could use an optional argument, e.g., using `xparse` to distinguish between storing an argument and output of an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand*{\testvalue}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\testvalue}{\def\testvalue{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
  Define: \test[some content]

  Show: \test, \test

  Define: \test[some other contents]

  Show: \test, \test.
\end{document}
```

But this would be against the principle that an optional argument should only modify the default behaviour of a command and not change it into a complete other command. So I would not recommend to do this.

Comment: The first use of \test{some content} will correctly set and keep the value for multiple further uses of \test, i.e. 

    \newcommand{\test}[1]{\renewcommand{\test}{#1}}
    \test{test}\test\test\test

will output testtesttest. It just doesn't redefine the value of \test when \test{new value} is used.

Comment: @Otis This is exactly what I said.

Comment: "The first usage of \test will redefine \test to a command without argument" doesn't this imply that a second use of just \test will no longer store the value? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.